# Wx-widgets - wxWebView - modify context menu

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Is there any method to modify or edit context menu in **"wxWebview"** .

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can modify the standard context menu but you should be able to disable it entirely with [EnableContextMenu(false)](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_web_view.html#af0e258bc270047afe6606ddec53bf70c) and then create and show your own menu from `wxEVT_CONTEXT_MENU` handler.

I didn't test this though.